# How can I Draw a Surface from a 3D path with an Arc in Asymptote?

Tags: asymptote, draw, arc

I am trying to color the area between Orgin and Arc with

```
path3 arcT=Arc(O, Tl, Tr);
path3 surfT = (O--arcT--cycle);
draw(surfT);
draw(surface(surfT),red);
```

But the Area remains Empty 
[image: Surface Works as shown with the green rectangle, Area between Arc and Origin is empty]
Surface in general does work as shown in the picture, what is going on?
How can I color the area between the arc and the origin?

Compilable Example

```
settings.outformat = "pdf";
settings.prc = false;
//settings.render = 0;
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
//label("Hello world!");
settings.inlinetex=true;
deletepreamble();
defaultfilename="Kugelintegral";
if(settings.render < 0) settings.render=4;
settings.outformat="";
settings.inlineimage=true;
settings.embed=true;
settings.toolbar=false;
viewportmargin=(2,2);
import three;
usepackage("bm");
size(8cm,0);
unitsize(1cm);
import solids;
import graph3;
import grid3;

currentprojection=perspective(camera=(-5,0,2),up=Y); // perspective(5,2,3);   //orthographic(10,15,3);

pen thickblack = black+0.75;
pen thickgreen = green+0.75;

//Arrow3(TeXHead2, emissive(thickblack)
real axislength = 1;
draw(L=Label("$x$", position=Relative(1.1), align=SW),
O--axislength*X, thickblack, arrow=Arrow3(TeXHead2)); //thickred
draw(L=Label("$y$", position=Relative(1.1), align=E),
O--axislength*Y,thickblack, arrow=Arrow3(TeXHead2)); //thickgreen
draw(L=Label("$z$", position=Relative(1.1), align=N),
O--axislength*Z,thickblack, arrow=Arrow3(TeXHead2)); //thickblue


real r=10;     // r=radius;
real q=0.125pi; //theta
real q_H = q/2;
real f=0.125pi; //phi
real f_H = f/2;
real h = cos(q/2)*r;
//real h=9.8481; // h=altitude section
triple rM=(0,0,h);

real q_ASY = sqrt(q_H^2+f_H^2);

triple M =  r*expi(0,0);
triple T =  r*expi(q_H,pi/2);
triple Tl = r*expi(q_ASY,pi/4);
triple Tr = r*expi(q_ASY,3pi/4);

//limits((0,0,0),1.2*(r,r,r));
dot("$\mathbf{p}_r$",O); 
dot("$M$",M);
dot("$T$",T);

dot("$Tl$",Tl);
dot("$Tr$",Tr);

//path3 arcT=Arc(O,r,180,0,ch,0,Y,50);
path3 arcT=Arc(O, Tl, Tr);
path3 surfT = (O--arcT--cycle);
draw(surfT);
draw(surface(surfT),red);
path3 g=(0,0,0)--(1,0,0)--(1,1,0)--(0,1,0)--cycle; 
draw(surface(g),green);
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between `Arc` and `arc`. `Arc` gives a better approximation but produces a large number of Bezier curves, the default value is around 400. It seems to be too large for the routine `surface(path3[])`, perhaps too small values to compute normal vectors to the surface.
So you have two solutions : reduce the number or use `arc`.
You can try

```
path3 arcT=Arc(O, Tl, Tr,50);
```

or

```
path3 arcT=arc(O,T1,Tr);
```

and you obtain

[image]

Comment: This solves the Problem, 
Thank you!